# Using loader on different Oracle version

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am working with a server and a client.

On the server, I have Oracle 12c installed, while I have the 11g on my client (pc).

When trying to load data onto my client, the batch file wasn't launching properly. There were no errors, and no log/bad files were generated, even though they were explicitly specified in the batch file.

My question is: Is this caused by a version mismatch? How should I work around this issue?

Comment: Generally speaking, Oracle is pretty good with backwards compatibility of client software vs server, at least for older clients interacting with newer versions of the server. So you'll need to give more details regarding *" the batch file wasn't launching properly"*. If there were no errors and nothing in the output files how do you know it didn't launch properly?

Comment: In theory, whether there was an error or not, I used to get a log file if it launches correctly, and a bad file if applicable. I didn't get any of these. Besides, there was no popup on the client, while I usually get some visual indicator that the batch file was launched

Comment: What were the exact commands that you ran (contents of your batch file)? What was the exact output of those commands?

Comment: `@echo off`
`sqlldr username/password@db data = filename.txt control = load.ctl bad = load.bad log = load.log`

Comment: Can the batch session even find the `sqlldr` binary then?

Comment: In theory it should, we always do the same Oracle installations onsite and this problem never occurred. Also the technician in charge didn't mention any problem